# Mudar coluna de uma Tabela no BD baseado em outra coluna da mesma Tabela

Tags: php

Eu tenho uma tabela `USERS` que possui as seguintes colunas:

```
username > usuário
stripe_active > Valor 0 ou 1
created_at > Data da Assinatura
subscription_ends_at > Será data final da assinatura
```

Quero saber se tem como montar uma rotina pra pegar a data em  `subscription_ends_at` e com base nela assim que o usuário efetuar o login se a data for igual ao do *BD* ou Superior, mudar a coluna `stripe_active` e mudar para **0**(Inativo).

Esta rotina seria colocada na página `header.php` e claro, todos os dados citados acima seriam lidos de acordo com cada usuário logado. O próprio sistema se encarregará de levar o usuário para a página de renovação de assinatura.

Comment: `username`, `stripe_active`, `created_at` e `subscription_ends_at` são realmente linhas? Ou são colunas? Essa `stripe_id` é uma outra coluna?

Comment: Opa, desculpa, são colunas. E quanto ao stripe_id está errado, é stripe_active e sim é uma coluna também. Não havia percebido o erro. espero que possa ajudar ;)

Comment: Quando ele fizer o login fazes um SELECT na BD a pesquisar a `subscription_ends_at` se for menor que a data atual fazes um UPDATE para de 1 para 0. E está feito.

Comment: Olá Jorge. Então, Como eu poderia implementar este SELECT baseado nestes dados? Desculpe minha falta de conhecimento.

Comment: Junior, é bem simples, quando você logar no sistema (ele faz um select correto?) é só pegar o ID e a data, depois você compara a data com a de hoje e faz um UPDATE TABLE SET CAMPO = 0 WHERE USER = ID

Comment: Pois então amigo, é aí que mora o perigo rsrs Eu não sei como fazer isso, e digo do código em si e onde devo colocá-lo :( ainda estou um tanto quanto "cru" nesse assunto.

Comment: Pessoal, seria algo como isso?  SELECT * FROM users WHERE subscription_ends_at < CURDATE()
UPDATE users SET stripe_active = 0 WHERE users = id